# Eclipse c++ giving me Invalid arguments if I write thread using lambda

Tags: c++, g++, eclipse-cdt

When trying to make thread using lambda with following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

int main() {
thread t([] {
    cout << "hello\n";
    });
t.join();
return 0;
```

Eclipse says:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
 thread(const std::thread &)
 thread(std::thread &&)
'   cpptest.cpp /cpptest/src    line 14 Semantic Error
```

Code compiles successfully, but that error is annoying, I also tried C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Dialect > Language Standard = ISO C++17, but without luck.

There may be problem with cpp checking setting, which are not set to higher cpp version, but I can't see that option in project setting.

Comment: _"There may be problem with cpp checking setting"_ Looks like that, yes.

Comment: I don't  have problem with build, build is successful. I want eclipse syntax checker to recognize that code as correct.

Comment: Ja. I just fired it up and tried it out myself. CODAN is barfing. CODAN is sort-of a high speed-but-imperfect compiler. It gets it wrong some times.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious, so see if brute force and ignorance helps you out. Right-click on the error in the Problems tab. Pick Quick Fix off the pop up menu. Accept the offer to suppress the message.  Eclipse will add a funky comment to your code telling it to shut the <expletive deleted>  up.

Comment: @user4581301  Yes, that partially solves that problem, but this only hides that error. So this is not global and permanent solution.

Comment: Wish I could give an actual solution. I have files full of inner classes that Eclipse just can't get right.